# Sort algorithms with time complexity in the order of number of elements

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

I am looking for an O(n) sort algorithm where n is the number of elements to sort. I know that highly optimized sorting algorithms are O(n log n) but I was told that under the following condition we can do better. The condition is:

- We are sorting numbers in a small enough range, say 0 to 100.

Comment: Use [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#Variant_algorithms) . You only need an array of size 101 to hold the counts for the number of instances of values from 0 to 100.

Answer (score 2):

Say we have the following

```
unsortedArray = [4, 3, 4, 2]
```

Here is the algorithm:

Step 1) Iterate over the `unsortedArray` and use each element as the index into a new array we call `countingArray`. The value we will hold in each position is the **count** of times that that number appears. Each time we access a position we increment it by 1.

```
countingArray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0, 0]   // before iteration
countingArray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0, 0]   // after handling 4
countingArray = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0, 0]   // after handling 3
countingArray = [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, ..., 0, 0, 0, 0]   // after the second 4
countingArray = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, ..., 0, 0, 0, 0]   // after handling 2
```

We can allocate `countingArray` in advance because the range of the numbers we wish to sort is limited and known a-priori. In your example `countingArray` will have 101 elements.

Time complexity of this step is O(n) because you are iterating over n elements from `unsortedArray`. Inserting them into `countingArray` has constant time complexity.

Step 2) As shown in the example above `countingArray` is going to have positions with value 0 where there were no numbers to count in `unsortedArray`. We are going to skip these positions in the following iteration we will describe.

In `countingArray` non-zero positions define a **number** that we want to sort, and the content in that position define the **count** of how many times that number should appear in the final `sortedArray`.

We iterate over `countingArray` and starting at the first position of `sortedArray` put that **number** into **count** number of adjacent positions. This builds `sortedArray` and takes O(n).

```
countingArray = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, ..., 0, 0, 0, 0]

// After skipping the first 2 0s and seeing a count of 1 in position 2
sortedArray = [2, 0, 0, 0]

// After seeing a count of 1 in position 3
sortedArray = [2, 3, 0, 0]

// In position 4 we have a count of 2 so we fill 4 in 2 positions
sortedArray = [2, 3, 4, 4]
```

=======

Total time complexity is O(n) * 2 = O(n)

Comment: Haven't you just reinvented Counting Sort but with an unnecessary complication by involving a Map instead of using the array from the start

Comment: Didn't mean to invent anything, just provide an answer @harold. I'll edit my post.